# How to label in dask dataframe with multi-conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

In pandas, I can tag in a new column with multi-conditions on different columns used by `np.where()`, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'],
                    'Sex':['Male','Female','Male'],
                    'Height':[175,160,195]})

df['Tag'] = ""
df['Tag'] = np.where((df['Sex'] == "Male")&(df['Height'] >180.),"CT",df['Tag'] )
df['Tag'] = np.where((df['Sex'] == "Female")&(df['Height'] <=180.),"GT",df['Tag'] )
print(df)
```

[image: result]

However, I didn't find out any functions in dask in a similar way. Using `.mask()` or `.where()` is not suitable for me.

I want to find out some functions in dask that is similar to `np.where()` that I can tag in a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

This might simplify your code. It's not using `dask`, but it's equally efficient.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'],
                    'Sex':['Male','Female','Male'],
                    'Height':[175,160,195]})

conds = [(df['Sex'] == "Male")&(df['Height'] >180.), (df['Sex'] == "Female")&(df['Height'] <=180.)]
val = ["CT", "GT"]

df['Tag'] = np.select(conds, val, default = np.NaN)
print(df)

Name     Sex  Height  Tag
0    A    Male     175  nan
1    B  Female     160   GT
2    C    Male     195   CT
```